# DDD modelling of articles, variants and their parameters

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am learning DDD and trying to model articles, its variants and parameters.

- Article can be on it's own without variants
- Variant **must** be child of an article
- both article and variant can have some parameters (colors, brands, sizes...), physical quantities (width, length, some article-specific like inner length)
- If you set some parameter on an article, it can be "synchronized" to it's children variants

  - you can override this in a variant by setting that parameter as "unlinked", then this variant would have different parameter value than article
- some parameters can be set multiple times (color: red, blue), but some only once (brand)
- those parameters are dynamically create, it's not a `Color` or `Brand` property but key-value selected from preconfigured values

I think my main aggregate roots will be Article and Variant.

My current code looks like this:

```cs
internal class Article : AggregateRoot<ArticleId>
{
    private readonly ISet<VariantId> _variants = new HashSet<VariantId>();
    private readonly ISet<AssignedParameter> _parameters = new HashSet<AssignedParameter>();
    private readonly ISet<AssignedPhysicalQuantity> _physicalQuantities = new HashSet<AssignedPhysicalQuantity>();

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Catalog { get; private set; }

    public IReadOnlySet<VariantId> Variants => _variants.AsReadOnly();
    public IReadOnlySet<AssignedParameter> Parameters => _parameters.AsReadOnly();
    public IReadOnlySet<AssignedPhysicalQuantity> PhysicalQuantities => _physicalQuantities.AsReadOnly();

    private Article(ArticleId id, string name, string catalog)
        : base(id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Catalog = catalog;
    }

    public static Article Register(ArticleId id, string name, string catalog)
    {
        var article = new Article(id, name, catalog);
        article.AddEvent(new ArticleRegistered(article.Id, article.Name, article.Catalog));
        return article;
    }

    public void AssignParameter(Parameter parameter, ParameterValue parameterValue, bool syncToVariants)
    {
        if (!parameter.CanBeAssignedMultipleTimes && _parameters.Any(p => p.ParameterId == parameter.Id))
        {
            throw new ParameterCanBeAssignedOnlyOnceException($"Parameter {parameter.Id} can by assigned only once.");
        }

        var assignedParameter = new AssignedParameter(parameter.Id, parameterValue.Id, syncToVariants);

        if (!_parameters.Add(assignedParameter))
        {
            throw new ParameterIsAlreadyAssignedException($"Parameter {parameter.Id} with value {parameterValue.Id} is already assigned.");
        }

        AddEvent(new ArticleParameterAssigned(Id, assignedParameter.ParameterId, assignedParameter.ParameterValueId));
    }

    public void UnassignParameter(Parameter parameter, ParameterValue parameterValue)
    {
        var assignedParameter = _parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParameterId == parameter.Id && p.ParameterValueId == parameterValue.Id);

        if (assignedParameter is null)
        {
            throw new ParameterIsNotAssignedException($"Parameter {parameter.Id} is not assigned.");
        }

        _parameters.Remove(assignedParameter);

        AddEvent(new ArticleParameterUnassigned(Id, assignedParameter.ParameterId, assignedParameter.ParameterValueId));
    }

    // physical quantity assign / unassign are similar to parameters
}
```

```cs
internal class Variant : AggregateRoot<VariantId>
{
    private readonly ISet<AssignedParameter> _parameters = new HashSet<AssignedParameter>();
    private readonly ISet<AssignedPhysicalQuantity> _physicalQuantities = new HashSet<AssignedPhysicalQuantity>();

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Catalog { get; private set; }
    public EanCode Ean { get; private set; }
    public decimal Weight { get; private set; }

    public IReadOnlySet<AssignedParameter> Parameters => _parameters.AsReadOnly();
    public IReadOnlySet<AssignedPhysicalQuantity> PhysicalQuantities => _physicalQuantities.AsReadOnly();

    internal Variant(VariantId id, string name, string catalog, EanCode ean, decimal weight)
        : base(id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Catalog = catalog;
        Ean = ean;
        Weight = weight;
    }

    // parameter and physical quantity assignment methods
}
```

Parameters:

```cs
internal class Parameter : AggregateRoot<ParameterId>
{
    private readonly ISet<ParameterValue> _values = new HashSet<ParameterValue>();

    public string Code { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public bool CanBeAssignedMultipleTimes { get; private set; }

    public IReadOnlySet<ParameterValue> Values => _values.AsReadOnly();

    public Parameter(ParameterId id, string code, string name, bool canBeAssignedMultipleTimes)
        : base(id)
    {
        Code = code;
        Name = name;
        CanBeAssignedMultipleTimes = canBeAssignedMultipleTimes;
    }
}

internal class ParameterValue : Entity<ParameterValueId>
{
    public string Code { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Parameter Parameter { get; private init; } = null!;

    public ParameterValue(ParameterValueId id, string code, string name)
        : base(id)
    {
        Code = code;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Value objects:

```cs
// for Article, variant doesn't have SyncToVariants property and has some other
internal class AssignedParameter : ValueObject
{
    public ParameterId ParameterId { get; private init; }
    public ParameterValueId ParameterValueId { get; private init; }
    public bool SyncToVariants { get; private init; }

    public AssignedParameter(ParameterId parameterId, ParameterValueId parameterValueId, bool syncToVariants)
    {
        ParameterId = parameterId;
        ParameterValueId = parameterValueId;
        SyncToVariants = syncToVariants;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return ParameterId;
        yield return ParameterValueId;
    }
}

internal class AssignedPhysicalQuantity : ValueObject { ... }
```

My questions:

1. What would be the best way to notify variants of the parameter change? I can think of two ways using events.

   First would be using `ArticleParameterChanged(ArticleId, parameter.Id, parameterValue.Id)`. I would handle this event and changed all variants at once in the handler - I don't think this is *the* way, but I wouldn't need to hold variants collection in article.

   Second would be to loop through variant IDs and create `ArticleVariantParameterChanged(ArticleId, VariantId, parameterId, parameterValueId)` event. This seems more correct to me?

   ```cs
   if (syncToVariants)
   {
       foreach (var variantId in _variants)
       {
           AddEvent(new ArticleVariantParameterChanged(Id, variantId, parameter.Id, parameterValue.Id);
       }
   }
   ```
2. How do I add new variant to article? The easiest way would be to create new variant and update the article in one transaction.

   ```cs
   // Article method
   public Variant RegisterVariant(VariantId variantId, ...)
   {
       var variant = new Variant(variantId, ...);
       _variants.Add(variantId);
       return variant;
   }

   // command handler? or domain service?
   var article = await _articleRepo.GetAsync(articleId);
   var variant = article.RegisterVariant(variantId, ...);
   await _variantRepo.AddAsync(variant);
   await _articleRepo.UpdateAsync(article);
   ```

   Or using events?

   ```cs
   // Article method
   public Variant RegisterVariant(VariantId variantId, ...)
   {
       var variant = Variant.Register(variantId, this.Id, ...);
       return variant;
   }

   // Variant static method
   public Variant Register(VariantId variantId, ArticleId articleId, ...)
   {
       var variant = new Variant(variantId, articleId, ...);
       variant.AddEvent(new VariantRegistered(variantId, articleId));
       return variant;
   }

   // command handler
   var variant = article.RegisterVariant(...);
   await _variantRepo.AddAsync(variant);

   // VariantRegisteredHandler
   article.AddVariant(variantId);
   ```

   However here it seems kind of confusing to me, `article.RegisterVariant` and `article.AddVariant`... Maybe it's just wrong naming?
   Also here can occur condition race between adding new variant and assigning a new parameter, when someone adds new parameter before the `VariantRegistered` event was handled, so it wouldn't sync that parameter.

   So I'm thinking, is it even good idea to store those shared parameters in each variant? Maybe it would be enough to just have variant specific parameters there and merge everything in the read model? However this would be harder to prevent duplications - if the article already has a parameter "color - red", assigning "color - red" to variant would need to check the article parameters too and there can be another race condition.
3. I read that entities without any domain business logic could be treated as CRUD, that means they wouldn't even inherit `AggregateRoot` and each of them would have own repository, right?
4. Let's say someone really wants to delete some parameter value, for example blue color. This wouldn't (hopefully) happen in my app, but I'm still curious how this would be handled. He confirms he really wants to delete it and I need to go through all articles and unassign it from them. How?

   My idea would be either to have `ParameterValueDeleted` event and `ParameterValueDeletedHandler` would query for all articles and variants and unassign it one by one, this handler would take really long time to execute.

   Or `ParameterValueDeletedHandler` would query for all IDs, create some event for them and *that* handler would unassign it later. However in the latter case I don't know how that event would be named to make sense. `UnassignArticleParameter` seems more like command than event and `ArticleParameterUnassigned` is something coming from article. Also I read that commands indicate something that can be rejected, so I would say command doesn't fit here.

   Also I see a problem when someone deletes that parameter and someone else queries for an article which doesn't have it unassigned yet - database join would fail because it would join to non existent parameter (considering single database for read and write model).
5. If I wanted to have mandatory parameters, where would be the best place to validate that all of them are set? Move the article registration logic to `ArticleFactory` and check it there? And for variants maybe `ArticleService` or `VariantFactory`? This seems kinda inconsistent to me, but maybe it's right?

   ```cs
   var article = await _articleRepo.GetAsync(articleId);
   _articleService.RegisterVariant(article, /* variant creation data */);
   _variantFactory.Register(article, /* variant creation data */);
   ```

---

I think this should be all, I hope I explained everything well.

I would appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Is there a reason why `Article` can't just have a collection of `Variant` and that `Variant` is not an aggregate root? Do you expect many people to modify different `Variant` of a given `Article` at the same time? For the sake of consistency it seems like having just one root would be much easier here.

Comment: @plalx That was my initial idea and sure it makes sense from the complexity point of view. There is no particular reason, I just thought it was too much unnecessary data for just changing color in one variant. So if the `Article` would have max 20 variants and each entity would have up to 50 parameters (maybe less) and 20 physical quantities, everything would be controlled only by a few people, do you think it would be ok to have this bigger root? I mean I don't know how big roots can be in big complex applications, maybe this is rather small and acceptable root (?)

Comment: Ultimately the roots are as big as they need to be to remain strongly consistent. In practice you may need to make concessions and accept eventual consistency. In very large distributed systems that are expected to scale very well you might go the eventual consistent route more often, but it's not always the right call. I would say, measure the impact of the large AR in practice (and theory) -- this means evaluating how often concurrency conflicts would occur and how much data (memory) will be loaded on average and then make a decision.

Comment: Performance is important and will force you to make concessions, but don't optimize prematurely. That said, the `Article` AR does look rather large though. If it's large, but not busy then perhaps a single AR is fine. If it's large AND busy then strong consistency won't cut it. If you go the eventually consistent route then evaluate what could be the impact of not having the fully consistent BIG PICTURE.